# I'm having trouble with putting PHP code on more than one line

Tags: php, html, web, formatting

```
<?php
$txt="Hello, my name is Max Koenig.";
$intro="I was Born and raised in Calgary, Alberta with my Mother, Father and Sister.";

echo $txt . " ". $intro;
echo strlen ("Hello, my name is Max Koenig.");



$t=date("H");

if ($t>"10")
    echo "Good Morning";

elseif ($t>"16")
    echo "Good afternoon";

elseif ($t>"19")
    echo "Goodnight"

?>
```

All of this is on one single line spanning across the page and I don't know how to make them on separate lines

Comment: Sounds like your file isn't being parsed by the webserver

Comment: To start a new line use a html line break: e.g. echo 'good morning <br />'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use HTML Break row tag after each PHP statement. Like

```
$txt="Hello, my name is Max Koenig. <br />"; $intro="I was Born and raised in Calgary, Alberta with my Mother, Father and Sister. <br />";
```